# Flatten multiple lines to a single one in vim, with or without a separator between them

Tags: vim

I'm pasting this on vim:

```
"recreation_ground"
"retail"
"farmyard"
"nature_reserve"
"scrub"
"park"
...
```

If I select these lines as a block, what command(s) may I use:

1. to "flat" their content to a single line,
   `"recreation_ground""retail""farmyard""nature_reserve""scrub""park"`
2. and (it would be perfect), adding a separator between them?
   `"recreation_ground","retail","farmyard","nature_reserve","scrub","park"`

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve these with blockwise visual mode.

First add the ',' at the end of each line:

```
<C-v>G$A,<ESC>
```

Then join those lines without space:

```
vGgJ
```

Checkout the help file to learn more

```
:h visual-block
:h gJ
```

Answer (score 2):

Many ways to skin a cat indeed.

With `:help :s`:

```
:'<,'>s/\n
```

for the first problem, and:

```
:'<,'>s/\n/,
$x
```

for the second one.

Note: there is a more "correct" way to solve problem #2, without the extra `$x`, but it is far less intuitive so YMMV:

```
:'<,'>s/\n"/,"
```

Answer (score 1):

Max Shen's solution seems the best one but there are many ways to skin a cat.

You can also use a `:norm` command to add the comma and then `J` to flatten everything.

First you select everything with:

```
gg #(go to the top)
v #(visual mode entire line)
GG #(bottom of file)
```

Run the norm command:

```
:
```

`'<,'>` should get inserted immediately you can then type norm and then a combination of keypresses that will be executed on each line in this case `A,` and then `<Enter>` to confirm.

You cna then wrap up by doing:

```
V
gg
J #(flatten/join selected section)
```